How to print GitHub Actions matrix values from another job?
Suppose I defined this job:
name: workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main2
jobs:

  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    strategy: 
      matrix:
        values: [val1, val2, val3, val4]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4   
  
    ....... (other steps here) .........


  job2:
    needs: [job1]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4   
      - name: List of matrix values
        run: |
          # I want to print matrix values here


whether printed as comma-separate values,
val1, val2, val3, val4

or in column with new-line separated values.
val1
val2
val3
val4

I tried:
name: workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main2
jobs:

  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    strategy: 
      matrix:
        values: [val1, val2, val3, val4]
      outputs:
        values: ${{ steps.values_id.outputs.values_array }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4   
  
    ....... (other steps here) .........
      - name: Export nuclei names
        id: values_id
        run: echo "values_array=${{ matrix.values }}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"



  job2:
    needs: [job1]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4   
      - name: List of matrix values
        run: |
          echo "${{ needs.job1.outputs.values }}"


which prints only the last executed matrix value instead of all of the matrix values.
I consulted matrix strategy from GitHub Actions documentation, I didn't find something relevant to my question.

What exactly is your use case? If you just want to share the matrix between multiple jobs, you can simply have a separate job to create the matrix and share the with the rest using an output parameter. Another solution could be to extract the matrix from the workflow file itself using yq (https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq).

which means there is no direct trivial way to extract those values and store them in an array or something similar.
My usage is very straightforward; my second job involves git commands which I wanted to commit with a message that includes each value separately, meanwhile, I don't want to use it in the first job because it causes conflicts in the repo backend. Hardcoding the values also is not favorable because I intend to change the values from time to time.

Yes, apparently no straightforward way is available. You'll have to resort to some intermediate processing to achieve this.

This should work:
job1:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  strategy: 
    matrix:
      values: [val1, val2, val3, val4]     
  steps:
    - run: echo ${{ matrix.values }} > value
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
      with:
        name: matrix-${{ matrix.values }}
        path: value

collect:
  needs: job1
  runs-on:  ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
      with:
        pattern: matrix-*
    - run: |
        cat */value

    - uses: geekyeggo/delete-artifact@v5
      with:
        name: matrix-*


Sorry, for the late reply, and thank you for the answer! Indeed, your answer succeeded in exporting those values using hashFiles but creates crowded artifacts with hash names that I can't filter out later on in other jobs using actions/download-artifact unless I specify the values in its name input which also I consider as redundant. As far as I know, actions/download-artifact doesn't support exclusion patterns whether in its name or pattern inputs, in contrast to actions/upload-artifact

Suppose I want to download all the artifacts specified by their names which correspond to the matrix values:
  - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
    with:
      name: # matrix values: val1, val2, val3, val4


Updated the answer to make artifact names more regulal. Also added an optional step to delete matrix artifacts

I didn't understand your comment, could you elaborate?
By the way, actions/download-artifact doesn't support selecting which artifact to download. Either one by one specified with name input, or using a pattern, or all of the artifacts which in the case of this answer can't help unless using multiple times of this action specified by the name value: val1, val2, etc.

Originally, atrifact had random and long names. You said that this created "crowded artifacts with hash names that I can't filter out". In the current solution, artifact names are short and they uniformly start with "matrix-". As a result of this naming change, these artifacts look like a distinct group in the UI. Another benefit of a common prefix is that it is easy now to delete these artifacts at the end of the workflow run. If you choose to delete them, you will avoid having a cluttered artifacts UI. I hope this answers your question.

Appreciated answer! Now it's clearer! Just to clear the dust in my mind, the only way to export those values is via a file and hence artifacts?

This is the only way if your matrix is defined as a static literal as in your question values: [val1, val2, val3, val4] If you create a more open question, I am sure there are other solutions.
